# Prove that there must be two distinct integers in $A$ whose sum is $104$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let A be any set of $20$ distinct integers chosen from the arithmetic
>   progression ${1,4,7,...,100}$. Prove that there must be two distinct
>   integers in $A$ whose sum is $104$.

Define $A=\{1+3i\}_{i=0}^{33}$. I know that if two distinct integers $a,b \in A$ are such that $104=a+b=(1+3i)+(1+3j)$, then $i+j=34$ with $0<i,j\leq33$ and $i \not= j$.

I think we can play with elements parity or even with the fact that if $i = j$, then $i = 17$ and $(3i + 1) = 52$. However, I am not able to advance further into the question. Are there someone who could help me complete the problem?

Comment: Hint:  there are $34$ such numbers.  Count the number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$ and $i+j=104$ you can make out of your set.  Then count the number of integers in your set that don't come up in any such pair.

Comment: I know we have 16 such pairs and 20 distinct integers to choose from the sequence. Must I use the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Yes.  But don't forget that some elements in your progression belong to no  such pair.

Comment: I already know that, i.e., when i=0 and i=j. Therefore, I may compute the ceiling of 32/20 = 2. So there must be two elements in which the sum gives 104. Is it right?

Comment: Not sure I get that last bit.  You can choose the two singletons ($1,52$) and you can take one from each of the $16$ pairs.  That's $18$ altogether.  Whatever you choose next has to complete a pair.  So, in fact, unless I have messed up you could replace $20$ in the problem with $19$.

Comment: ..or we can make a stronger statement there must be *two* distinct pairs that add to 104.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: How many ways can two integers from the progression add up to 104. Lets write them down

$$4+100, 7+97,10+94,\cdots 49+55$$

Those are 16 pairs. We can't take two from any pair, otherwise they would sum to 104.

Comment: I already know, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(**Historical remark**)

This problem is **Putnam** $78/A1$. You can find a solution [**here**](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol781.html):

> Not best possible: we can make do with $19$ elements. Note that the numbers have the form $3n + 1$ for $n = 0, 1, \ldots, 33$. We seek $3n + 1$, $3m + 1$ so that $n + m = 34$. Evidently $n = 0$ and $n = 17$ do not help. The other $32$ numbers form $16$ pairs with the required sum. So if we take $19$ numbers then we are sure to get two from the same pair.